# Htaccess: Hide parameter's value or querystring from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My current url is  /html/Home.php?v=val1&t=val2 .
I want to hide val1 and val2 from url using htaccess. val1 and val2 value changes dynamically.
I have searched for solutions,but solutions found on this site are not working in my project. I need URL as follows: /html/Home/ or /html/Home/v/t

Comment: It is ok if I keep home.php as it is. I just want to hide parameter's values.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

```
RewriteRule ^html/Home/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) html/Home.php?v=$1&t=$2 [NC,L]
```

For dynamic parametres you have to use only like that.

Comment: Thanks for help.It is not working. Do I need to add any extra condition or statement with above statement?

Comment: @user3522186, But i am using my application url's in the same way..here its working..where you facing the problem?..what error you get ?